# ui5 - two aggregations for one calendar

Tags: sapui5

im trying to bind two different aggregations to my calendar.
i have access to both.

im trying to get a calendar where dates from both sets are displayed and can be edited.

what is the best way of doing this?

first aggregation:

```
oCalendar.bindAggregation("specialDates", {
            path: constant.context.localSpecialDates,
            template: oView.byId("templateSpecialDates")
        });
```

second aggregation:

```
oCalendar.bindAggregation("specialDates", {
            path: constant.context.globalSpecialDates,
            template: oView.byId("templateSpecialDates")
        });
```

the second one overwrites the first one naturally.

what is the best way of implementing both sets in my calendar?

Comment: Create a new object where the global and local dates are joined

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the best way is to create a local json model which contains your sets and bind it. Or you can easily expand the binding with a NavigationProperty.

Comment: dont i have to still add add  a second aggregation then?

Comment: If you are using two sets you have to go for the json model